# I have a user that can only see a task description if in edit mode!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For any given task that the user has, she can only view any text from the description field only if she edit's the item can she view that text.

Answer (score 0):

- Check her permissions.
- Try with another browser. Maybe it's a browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can she view text from the description field in display form?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Create a new task list to check if the same issue will occur.
2. Add the site into the trusted site in IE.
3. Check if there is custom code in the display form.

Comment: She can only see it in edit mode